# TrackballControls wrong object rotation on left side

Tags: javascript, three.js

I use three.js TrackballControls for rotating object.
Here is simple application - http://zheden.elitno.net/

I cannot rotate object horizontally when mouse position is on left side of scene. Vertical rotation is ok. 
Could you please tell me what is wrong?

Here is my code:

```
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, 1, 0.1, 1000);
        var controls;

        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize(500, 500);
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(1,1,1);
        var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial(
                            {
                              overdraw: true,
                              color: 0x00aa80,
                              shading: THREE.FlatShading
                            });
        var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        scene.add(cube);

        var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
            directionalLight.position.x = 1; 
            directionalLight.position.y = 1; 
            directionalLight.position.z = 1; 
            directionalLight.position.normalize();
            scene.add( directionalLight );

            var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
            light.position.set( -1, -1, -1 );
            scene.add( light );

            var light1 = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x222222 );
            scene.add( light1 );

        camera.position.z = 3;

        controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera );

            controls.rotateSpeed = 1.0;
            controls.zoomSpeed = 1.2;
            controls.panSpeed = 0.8;

            controls.noZoom = false;
            controls.noPan = false;

            controls.staticMoving = true;
            controls.dynamicDampingFactor = 0.3;

            controls.keys = [ 65, 83, 68 ];

            controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );


        function render() {
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }

        function animate()  {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);


            controls.update();


            render();
        };

        animate();
```

Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest moving to the latest release of three.js. You are using r49 and the latest is r58. Your issue could have been fixed.

Comment: Updated to r58. The same..

Comment: As this examples/misc_controls_trackball.html also has a blind spot on the left and the right, I would say that the controls work as designed.